# Asymptotics of $\mathbb E[-\log(p)]$ in a one-sample t-test as $n\to\infty.$

Tags: t-test, p-value, asymptotics

Consider a one-sample two-sided t-test, i.e. $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are iid. $N(\mu, \sigma)$ random variables and we want to test $H_0\colon \mu=0$ versus $H_A\colon \mu\neq0$.

The $t$-statistic  is compared against the tails of a t-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom, to result in a $p$-value. For the expected value of $t$, we have $\mathbb{E}[t] = \frac{\mu}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}$. In that setting, what is the asymptotic relation between $\mathbb{E}[-\log(p)]$ and $n$?

We can computationally investigate this relation by running a large number of t-tests, computing $p$ and [plotting](https://github.com/frederikziebell/p_value_asymptotics/blob/main/pval.md) the sample mean of $-\log(p)$ versus $n$ for different values of $\mu/\sigma$.

[image]

This indicates that the relation between $\mathbb{E}[-\log(p)]$ and $n$ might be asymptotically linear. If so, what is the slope of this relation in terms of $\mu/\sigma$?

Comment: 1. The $p$ value is a *random variable*; it is a function of the sample. Your plots show no sampling noise at all. What are you actually plotting here? 2. The t-statistic is also a random variable, you don't observe its expected value.  3. Its expected value under H1 is not what you have there. 4. Why would a transformed expected value be useful in considering the properties of p-values?

Comment: ... noting here that p is a nonlinearly transformed $T$ (indeed non-monotonic for two tailed tests). [It seems like you're trying to plot p at a particular value for $T=t$, but it's not clear what that tells you about p-values, though I'm not certain that's what you're plotting there.]

Comment: To clarify: Your title makes sense to me, but your discussion in the body text does not seem to relate to computing $E[-\log(p)]$.

Comment: The red dots in this plot indicate approximately where I think $E[-\log(p)]$ should be in your first display https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUmiO.png ... If you're interested in the asymptotic shape, however, you can simplify a number of things about this problem.

Comment: @Glen_b I clarified the text. I mistakenly thought that I can plug [t] into the CDF of the t-distribution to compute [−log()]. I edited the question and added simulations to approximate [−log()].

Comment: $E(T) =E[\sqrt{n} \frac{(\bar{X}-\mu_0)}{s}] = \sqrt{n} E[ \frac{\bar{X}}{s}] =\sqrt{n} E[ \bar{X}]\cdot E|\frac{1}{s}]\neq  \sqrt{n} \mu\cdot \frac{1}{\sigma}$  (using independence of $\bar{X}$ and $s$ for normal random variables).

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\sigma =1$, known. Set $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = S_n$, and assume we obtain positive values (to avoid examining positive and negative cases that behave equivalently). Then for large $n$

$$p_n = 2\cdot \left[1- \Phi\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right] = 2\Phi\left(-\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right).$$

Add and subtract using the true non-zero mean $\mu$,
$$ p_n = 2\Phi\left(-\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{n\mu}{\sqrt{n}} -\frac{n\mu}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = 2\Phi\left(-{\sqrt{n}( \bar X - \mu)} -\sqrt{n}\mu \right) = 2\Phi\left(-Z -\sqrt{n}\mu\right).$$

$Z$ is a standard Normal, no longer depending on $n$. Then

$$-\log p_n = -\log2 \Phi\left(-Z -\sqrt{n}\mu\right) $$

$$\implies \frac{\partial (-\mathbb E\log p_n)}{\partial n} = -\mathbb E\left[\frac{\phi\left(Z +\sqrt{n}\mu\right)}{\Phi\left(-Z -\sqrt{n}\mu\right)}\cdot \left(-\frac 12 n^{-1/2}\mu \right)\right]$$

We know that (inverse Mill's ratio or hazard rate)
$$\frac{\phi\left(Z +\sqrt{n}\mu\right)}{\Phi\left(-Z -\sqrt{n}\mu\right)} \to Z +\sqrt{n}\mu$$

so

$$\frac{\partial (-\mathbb E\log p_n)}{\partial n} \to \mathbb E\left[\frac{Z +\sqrt{n}\mu}{2\sqrt{n}}\mu\right] \to \frac 12 \mu^2,$$

which is constant so indeed it appears that the relation is asymptotically linear. Divide the limit by $\sigma^2$ for non-unitary variance.